# Incremental backup in postgresql in windows

Tags: postgresql, backup, postgresql-9.5

I am developing an application with postgresql as backend. So my requirement is to take the incremental backup either hourly or daily basis.
I have gone through many related articles (like https://coderwall.com/p/jxebnw/incremental-backups-for-postgresql) but i found that postgresql database does not support incremental backup independently. It means that the postgresql needs third party tools like pg_rman in order to get incremental backup. Also the pg_rman tools only works on UNIX not windows.

Is it really so? I mean its hard to believe that the database like postgresql do not support incremental backup.

So my question is do postgresql support incremental backup independently? If yes then what is the procedure for achieving it.

Comment: No, you don't need external tools. You can do incremental backups using WAL archiving: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/continuous-archiving.html

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is right that the incremental backups are not possible in postgresql.

I don't know if there is an alternative for pg_rman in windows but you can achieve the incremental backup in postgres with the continuous archiving. Which can be later restored with PITR (point in time recovery)

Details on:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/continuous-archiving.html

Comment: WAL archiving **is** an incremental backup. So the statement "incremental backups are not possible" is wrong.

Comment: To be precise, wal archiving is not incremental backup but only the backup of WAL files, which can be used as an alternative to the incremental backups.

Comment: You can add these archived WALs for recovery through these files.

Comment: I followed that page https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/continuous-archiving.html but its little unclear to me mainly the restore part. Also i don't get how i schedule the incremental backup either hourly or daily.